# maintainable way of injecting dependencies in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering how can I inject dependencies in more readable way in angular. I am  more interested in AMD(requirejs) way. Like following:

```
define(function (require) {
    var ModuleOne = require("ModuleOne"),
        ModuleTwo = require("ModuleTwo");

    var ThisModule = (function () {
          // code here
    })();

    return ThisModule;
});
```

**Is it possible to inject dependencies above way in angularjs or is there any better way to do it then current way in angularjs?**

Answer (score 2):

From the Angular JS [official website](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

> Angular modules solve the problem of removing global state from the
>   application and provide a way of configuring the injector. **As opposed
>   to AMD or require.js modules, Angular modules don't try to solve the
>   problem of script load ordering or lazy script fetching**. These goals
>   are orthogonal and both module systems can live side by side and
>   fulfil their goals.

Hence, purpose of both the libraries(RequireJS and AngularJS) is totally different. The dependency injection system built into AngularJS deals with the **objects** needed in a component; while dependency management in RequireJS deals with the **modules** or, **JavaScript files**.

In requireJS, Objects of loaded modules are cached and they are served when same modules are requested again. On the other hand, AngularJS maintains an injector with a list of names and corresponding objects. In this case, Object is served whenever it is referenced using the registered name.

Generally we inject dependencies in angularJS like

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope,greeter){

});
```

If you want an alternative way to inject dependencies in angularJS, you may do something like.

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem with this is that if a controller requires too many dependencies then there are bunch of parameters required in controller's callback function. I want to reduce that amount somehow.

Comment: Use  `MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];` syntax then. It makes your code look more readable than the conventional approach.

Comment: that is possible however, that doesn't solve my problem. because I still need too many parameters for too many dependencies like `var MyController = function($scope, greeter, dep3, dep4, dep5, dep6, dep7, dep8, dep9, dep10, dep11, dep12, dep13) {
  // ...
}`

Comment: You may create a  `service` with all these dependencies and use that service in controller. This would make your controller readable, though your service would look cumbersome. However, there's no way you can *skip* a dependency if its being used by your service/controller.

Comment: You can move your dependencies to a different service/factory, but cannot avoid them. `someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope,greeter,myService){ ... });` ... where myService is a factory containing all required dependencies.  `someModule.factory('myService',function(dep3, dep4, dep5, dep6, dep7, dep8, dep9, dep10, dep11, dep12, dep13){ ... })`.